# Adding Long html with createDocumentFragment with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to add a lot of html with Javascript and there is a problem when I try to add `<td>` after that everything works perfectly:

Here is my Html:

```
<tr class='vis_par' id='row_wa' value="2"></tr>
```

Here is my Script:

```
var sec_nom='wa';
document.querySelector(".vis_par[value=2]").appendChild(createFragment(" 
<td> <img src='"+sec_nom+".png' alt=''> </td>
<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_"+sec_nom+"_val' type='text' size=7> </td> 
<td> </td> 
<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_"+sec_nom+"_imp' type='text' size=7> </td> "));

function createFragment(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}
```

I expect this result:

```
<tr class='vis_par' id='row_wa' value="2">
  <td><img src='wa.png'></td>
  <td><input class='num_vo' id='vo_wa_val' type='text' size=7></td>
  <td> </td>
  <td><input class='num_vo' id='vo_wa_imp' type='text' size=7></td>
</tr>
```

But im having this:

```
<tr class='vis_par' id='row_wa' value="2">
  <img src='wa.png'>
  <input class='num_vo' id='vo_wa_val' type='text' size=7>
  <input class='num_vo' id='vo_wa_imp' type='text' size=7>
</tr>
```

I don't know where are my `<td>`!!

Comment: Try wrapping `<tr>` in <`table>` and `<tbody>`

Comment: It's already wrapped, it is just part of the main code

Comment: `function createFragment(htmlStr)` When you call `createFragment` where is `htmlStr` ? Is `var htmlStr =document.querySelector(".vis_par[value=2]").appendChild(createFragment(" .....` ?

Comment: htmlStr is all my html, is the variable that createFragment recieve

Comment: I don't see it outside of function...

Comment: createFragment(" 
<td> <img src='"+sec_nom+".png' alt=''> </td>
<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_"+sec_nom+"_val' type='text' size=7> </td> 
<td> </td> 
<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_"+sec_nom+"_imp' type='text' size=7> </td> ")

Comment: My bad, ok. I see it. You don't want to use Ajax to inject the fragment?

Comment: Don't overlook [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the `2` in selector `".vis_par[value='2']"` . Process could be simplified using `.innerHTML`

```js
var sec_nom = 'wa';
document.querySelector(".vis_par[value='2']").innerHTML =
  "<td> <img src='" + sec_nom + ".png' alt=''> </td>" 
  + "<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_" + sec_nom + "_val' type='text' size=7> </td>"
  + "<td> </td>" 
  + "<td> <input class='num_vo' id='vo_" + sec_nom + "_imp' type='text' size=7> </td>";
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class='vis_par' id='row_wa' value="2"></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing! This solve my problem. I'm migrating all my jquery code to Javascript and im having this kind of questions. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

I made a HTML page with the identical markup you had in your fragment. The error claims that it's unexpected to have `<td>` without `<table>` and `<tr>` so it'll be ignored. That explains why your `<td>` never made it.

[image: TD Error]

OP:*I want to use this query to insert all the html in tr already created*

That's understandable, so I made a demo that does exactly what you want. For details you can read the demo's **[README.md](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtAE1E0PtnNvrw17SAX6?p=info)** file.

This function is the heart of the demo:

```
    (function() {

        xhr();

        function xhr() {
            var tags, i, clone, file, xhttp;
            tags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                if (tags[i].getAttribute("data-x")) {
                    clone = tags[i].cloneNode(false);
                    file = tags[i].getAttribute("data-x");
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                            clone.removeAttribute("data-x");
                            clone.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                            tags[i].parentNode.replaceChild(clone, tags[i]);
                            xhr();
                        }
                    }
                    xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
                    xhttp.send();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    })();
```

Details on `xhr()` are in the [**README.md**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtAE1E0PtnNvrw17SAX6?p=info) file. Here's the [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtAE1E0PtnNvrw17SAX6?p=preview).

---

---

Answer (score 0):

You can't create document fragment with just `td` you need to wrap the tags in `<table><tbody><tr>` the same as jQuery does.

Comment: I want to use this query to insert all the html in tr already created